# How to scale Scrapy spiders with thousands of websites?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I know that there are several questions about how to scale spiders (e.g. group spiders in one class and use `CrawlerProcess`) but I haven't found out the best scenario for my case.

The plan:

- 10.000 completely different websites (just get all the text found and/or download PDFs)
- At the moment I only have a single IP

Should I use `scrapyd` in any case? Should I use `CrawlerProcess` in any case? Do I need more IPs although the sites have no strict security? I am also thinking about creating base spiders with specific subvariants and hope that each of them can handle multiple sites. `Scrapydweb` seems nice but I think only for a few hundreds of websites.

How can I tackle the challenge scalability?

What is your recommendation?

Comment: Hey Daniel, this question is way too broad for stackoverflow. What you're refering to is called broad crawling and there's a lot to do to get it working correctly. I also suggest looking into data formats like WARC which can store more than just HTML text.

Comment: I just wanted to share some insights to get a feeling about the complexity of the crawling. I don't need a answer that solves everything but I am interested in wich direction I should go. Broad crawling sounds very good. I will look into that.